# Stop rendering window in its onloaded event WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I defined a View as an instance of class SubWindow which is defined as following

```
public partial class SubWindow : Window
{
    public SubWindow(BaseViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        vm.CloseWindow += (s, e) => this.Close();
        vm.Hide += (s, e) => this.Hide();
        this.Content = vm;
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BaseViewModel vm = DataContext as BaseViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
        {
            vm.OnInitDialog()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my ViewModel base class

```
public class BaseViewModel() // implements INotifyPropertyChanged
{   
    public event EventHandler CloseWindow;

    public virtual bool OnInitDialog()
    {        
    }


    public virtual void OnCancel(object param)
    {
        CloseWindow(null, null);
    }
}
```

And then my concrete ViewModel class

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel() 
    {
        // Init ViewModels
    }
    public bool OnInitDialog()
    {

        if(check()) 
        {
           OnCancel(null);
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is how I show my Window

```
MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
Window window = new SubWindow(vm);
window.ShowDialog();
```

When the window is loaded, OnLoaded event is raised.

Inside OnLoaded event it will call ViewModel's OnInitDialog method.

The problem is inside OnInitDialog(), if check() returns true then OnCancel() will be invoked, which in turn invokes ViewModel's CloseWindow() and View's Close().

In other word, Window's Close() is called inside its ShowDialog() which is not a good practice in my opinion.

And sometimes it raises exception if the solution is built in release mode.

So my question is how to stop rendering window after it is loaded.

Comment: Your feeling about calling close inside OnLoaded seem right. But how is 'stop rendering' a solution?

Comment: And what about the `vm == null` case, that is confusing.

Comment: Sorry for using the wrong words. I meant how to unload a window after its ShowDialog is called. About vm == null case, you're right. It should never happen. I just add it for safety reason.